# Trouble to send data packet to a servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, communication

I have created an android app which sends live audio packets to the server. The android code is working fine, as I have tested it on a java class. Now, I have converted the class to a java servlet and tried to do the same but I am getting the **unknown host exception**.

The **servlet code**:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AudioServlet", urlPatterns = {"/AudioServlet"})
public class AudioServlet extends HttpServlet {

    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    static AudioInputStream ais;
    static AudioFormat format;
    static boolean status = true;
    static int port = 50005;
    static int sampleRate = 8000;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet AudioServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet AudioServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);

        /**
         * Formula for lag = (byte_size/sample_rate)*2 Byte size 9728 will
         * produce ~ 0.45 seconds of lag. Voice slightly broken. Byte size 1400
         * will produce ~ 0.06 seconds of lag. Voice extremely broken. Byte size
         * 4000 will produce ~ 0.18 seconds of lag. Voice slightly more broken
         * then 9728.
         */
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[5000];

        format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

        while (status == true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);

            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    receivePacket.getData());

            ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());
            toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());

        }

    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
        try {

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            sourceDataLine.open(format);

            FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            volumeControl.setValue(6.0206f);

            sourceDataLine.start();
            sourceDataLine.open(format);

            sourceDataLine.start();

            System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

            sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
            System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The **android code**:

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity {
    private Button startButton, stopButton;

    public byte[] buffer;
    public static DatagramSocket socket;
    private int port = 50005;
    AudioRecord recorder;

    private int sampleRate = 8000;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig,
            audioFormat);
    private boolean status = true;


    int bufferSizeInBytes;
    int bufferSizeInShorts;
      int shortsRead;
      short audioBuffer[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                status = true;
                startStreaming();


            }

        });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder released");

            }

        });

        minBufSize += 5120;
        System.out.println("minBufSize: " + minBufSize);
    }


    public void startStreaming() {

        Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                    Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                    DatagramPacket packet;

                    final InetAddress destination = InetAddress
                            .getByName("192.168.1.20");
                    Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");

                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION,
                            sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat,
                            minBufSize * 10);
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                    recorder.startRecording();

                    while (status == true) {

                        // reading data from MIC into buffer
                        minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        // putting buffer in the packet
                        packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,
                                destination, port);

                        socket.send(packet);
                        System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " + minBufSize);

                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                }
            }

        });
        streamThread.start();
    }


}
```

**The url for the servlet is** :

```
http://192.168.1.20:8084/AudioStreamWebApplication/AudioServlet
```

**How should I call the URL from the android class to send the data packets?**

Comment: have u added permission ?

Comment: I guess you are talking about  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>        Yes, I have done it

Comment: Is your phone on the same network as the webserver?

Comment: i cannot open the above url ..

Comment: @MT8 Yes it is, you cannot open it because it is hosted in my local network

Comment: Are you sure? Can you inspect the IP-address on your phone?

Comment: @NilsH yes I can, one thing, the address to the servlet is long, but the android code only takes the IP address and the port, will it be able to connect?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Can you explain?

Comment: @NilsH the url I have pasted contains "/AudioStreamWebApplication/AudioServlet" alson with IP address and port no..........but if you check the android code you will see that only the IP address and the port is supplied

Comment: Ok, not sure I fully understand, but it would not respond with unknown host anyway as long as the ip and port is correct. Can you access the servlet from other computers on the same network?